# Making an object to reach Jupiter's core and return information?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

Would it be possible to create a probe which could survive the crushing pressures and temperatures to reach the solid core of Jupiter and return data to Earth? What would make this impossible? This is with any possible technology, not current tech.

Comment: With current technology, or with scientifically possible technology?

Comment: This question can't really be answered as-is. A meaningful answer would require defining what kind of technology is available to solve the engineering problem.

Comment: For your interest:- Asimov's [Not Final!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Final!).

Comment: You'd simply sidestep into one of the other spatial dimensions (which may be curled up so they are only 1mm or less in extent... might have to stretch them a bit) far enough that you can safely traverse to Jupiter's core, then observe at your leisure. Probably gravitically, since visible light (or any other) doesn't penetrate extradimensionally.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes it is possible

The "probe" would be a [Relativistic Kill Missile](https://vocal.media/futurism/relativistic-kill-vehicle) carrying enough kinetic energy to overcome the [gravitational binding energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy) of Jupiter. The resulting explosion of the gas giant will return a lot of data about its former interior structure.

A job well done? Maybe. But definitely done.

Comment: And then the Vogon Constructor Fleet can start working on that Interstellar Bypass.

Comment: Well, keeping Jupiter whole was not a requisite, +1.

Comment: Less efficient but about as elegant as what V'Ger does.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with current technology or any foreseeable technology within the next hundred years. The pressures within the deeper levels of Jupiter's atmosphere are simply too high for any material object to withstand. Apart from that escape from the gravitational pull of Jupiter starting at the core under such circumstances would also be beyond current technology or any foreseeable technology.

Comment: Jupiter, heck, it's not even possible to send a probe to EARTH'S core within those limits.